# Using PHP I issue a simple query of a MySQL database - I get an error, when issuing the same query in phpMyAdmin I get rows of information

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've run this on my local windows machine and on an ubuntu server with the same results.

Query to run in PHP:

```
$job_sql="SELECT * FROM job WHERE job_title = 'SIP Opportunities where sipsubmitted EQ 1 and still in BAB PROCESS'";

$job_ret = mysql_query($job_sql);

$job_row = mysql_fetch_array($job_ret,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Error from PHP Script:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   C:\wamp\www\tracker\inc\common.php on
>   line 489

Other similar queries work fine in same script (different job_titles).

phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * 
FROM job
WHERE job_title = 'SIP Opportunities where sipsubmitted EQ 1 and still in BAB PROCESS'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0004 sec) - successfully found the row!!!

Comment: Use `echo mysql_error();` to see the error you are getting in PHP

Comment: Have you tried something like printing the result of mysql_error() before passing $job_ret to mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: did you select the database first in your php script?

Comment: Are both queries using the same account/password/connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have misplace a single quote in your example code.  With the code as it is now, you're looking for the following job title:

'SIP Opportunities where sipsubmitted EQ 1 and still in BAB PROCESS'

Did you mean for that entire string to be the `job_title`?